# Confusion between Bytes, Hex and string in Python 3

Tags: python, string, unicode, encoding, hex

I have a log file that contains hex strings. I have to convert it back to a legible sentence. However, I am noticing some erratic behavior during string processing.

For example, the shortest line in log file is

```
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
```

I use the following snippet to convert it to *bytes* object

```
binascii.unhexlify(line[:-1])
```

The *[:-1]* to remove the *endline* character at the end.

I get a *bytes* object back as follows

```
b'\x82\t\x9f\xd4\xe8d13\xb8T\xc8B#\x1e3\xfe\x99`\x1a\xdf\xbb2\xfe\x19\x07\r\xc7\xb6e\xc2\x7fE\x10\xec\xcd\xd2\x0c\x8ch\xb9\xff\xe6\xfb\x94\x15T\xcbg_\x92\xfd\xfd\x04:xU\xf8\xe5\xec\x1fK\x18iY_.\xe3\xe8\x92i\xd3\x03\\w\xb3\xe7\xd5 \xdcxo\xec\xc6\x07L#VZ]\xe9\x83v\'\xe6vgk\xdb\xfd\xed\xa5\xd5\xb5(\x95\xb2\xcc\xda\xaa7;\\\xc8\xca~\x92}\x88]\xb6\xd6\x9f\xed!u\xdff\xb2=!\xb9;[\xdb\xb6\x19\xbb\xdeu\xb3\x9a\xcdB\xd7gx%\x9aJ6SG>t\xfc\xd0\xec\x01\x82@\x1a\xc56yg\xc1\xd8\xdey\xcb\x98\xfa\xb4\xbfs\xb5a  B\xdd\x94\x85<\x0e\x13u\xfb\xd1G7}\xe4\x8cpP\xf6`\xaf/U\xc5r\xacS8N<\'\x0c\x95\xa2\x07g2oX\x01\x119!|\xef3\xaeM\xd5\xd9H5\xa1qz\xd6\rG\x8b3]Mx\x90\x1fQF|\r\x9es\x03/\x95\xdf\x83O\x01\x05\x01*\xe3\xa9\xe2\xb8+\xe5\x98\x1e4\x0e$\xb7\x12\x82\xb0\x02\xc5\x12\xd1&\xc1\xc6\xed\xc8h\xcd\x13\xca\xc1\x90\xa9#\xcdX\xe6\xec\x08\xe4\x84&\xd1\xf7\x99i\x83>D\x99e\x0e\x18F\xc99\x83\xef\xc16J\xce\x99N\xbf.\x12\xfeA\xaa\x0e#!K\x1f\x04\x17n\xc31\x96s\x95\xfdO>\xf3t\xf3M\xc5\xed1\x07H9\x8d\x87R\x8e>\xb0\xcc\xdea\x13\x15\x1dL\xd8cM\xc7U\xe5q\xa78:\x1a\xbd\xbd\xa4\xbc\x9a6\x0cu\xb4Db\x8b_\xea\x07Z:\xb5\xac\x9d\x16\x9cVVE\xed:\x14\x99|=n\x1ebQaa\x98j%\x1a\xe4\xc2\xc3\xd7L$\x87H\xd9V\xff\xdb\xaaM\xcck\xbd\x11\xd2\xf8_\x00\xfd\xf2\x8c\xbb\x0bK\xb2\x1400\xd0\xd3\xb5\xd0\xd3QulS\x87\x85\xd5D\xc7u\xbb\xe5\x04\x08\x96\x16\xd3,\x19\x03\xaa\xb5\xf9>\x98l*Y\xdf\xec-\x8eZ8\x05c\xd3\xf2K\xe2\x89\x185\xcd[\xc6\xbfs\xc4\x806D\xee\x9d]\x10\x9c&H\xe7o\xabi\x03\xa6\xb8\xbd\xe9\x8d\xe2\x9cXE\xb5P\xb7\xcd\xa86h\xf1po\\S\x88\x01\x0e \r\x19T#\x0cL\xdf\x18\xc8$5l\xfb\x8c\x01\xa1\xf9\x84\x93\xcd\xd42\x11\x95\xad\xf0\xd2\xcf7\x95\x1a\x19\x14)\xb8\xb9\xe5\x06-\\\x17\xfcm5j\xf5\xfd4\xfc\xfb\x87J\x9d\xf3\x9b\xed\x83\xdc\xed\x18+\xec\xd0\x9e\xd1\xd8\xbe.\x85=;\x1f\x13\x97\xee\xed\xdc\xf3\xbb\xb9\x1d\xcel\x1b\xb7\xb7\xdd\xbe~\x98\xbd8>\xfb\xf0\xe1\x92T\xcb\xf4\x89\xae\x8be\x96\xc0\xe4t7l\xd8\xf5U\xb3\xb8\xc1nI\x1e\x86\xb4\x19_@\xf6Big\xc4P\xdb\xc9\xa0\x1d\xbf-}\x05Cp\x17\x00("\xccV \x96\xd1\x94U&k\xfe\x0cy\x81\x81\x8e^\x85\x90UZ\xf3\xef.O9\xfcp\x028\x05\tTC\xf5\xbeg;\xe6\x8e\xd9\x9c\xd8#\xd8.+\x83\x11\x177{\t\xeaCu\xae\xfbm\xacu\xd2\xc4h&N="\xaa\x10q\xaa\xac"\x0c\xe1\x05$$\xe8_\xc2\xb5-\x1b"v;~[J\x99\x92\xf5\xc6|\x1d^\xad%S\\\xabW\n\xb5\xc1\xc9u,9\xd0\xa7k\xd0\xff\xd0\xbb\x9b\xc7\xe0e.\xdfp\x14\xd4\xda\x98da\x9bM\x1e\xd1\x0c/<Z;\x86>,\x8e\x06\xa9G\xc81\xd1\xf3(\xc8$O\x1f\x85<O/D\xeeI\xeb.\xe4%\x1e\xae\xbc\x1aN\xf0\xf0\xa4\x18\xff\xf0A\xf3>\x9c]X\xe9\x04\xf1\x98\xbd\x0e#\xabrd\xa1\x9f?\xf1\xd1K\x8e\xe0\x02\x0fY\x1e\xfbvs\xbd\x1e\xc1=7c|\x10[D/\xc2\xaf\x82\xb4\x89\x02\xb0\xb2+\xe9\x08m\x0c\xdf1HP\x0cb\xf7*\x06\x99I\x80\x86?/\x0eI\xc1\xd6\xe3\xa6U\x95\xc6\x1a\xa6\xdb\xb8\xd5\\\xe30\xc6\x17\xd8\xa1\xf3\xdf!\x93G\xeb\xecN.\xd4\x80\x95  \x8b:\xf5\x88\x07\x1eB\xfd\xf7!\xc1vk\xf1F\x1f\xda\xd8\x9f\x00\xb5\xdd\xa5\xd6\xf58\xd8\xe5\x17T+\xd9I\xb1\xd62Ob]\x03\x0bYs\xf6\xd0\xfc\xfc\x89$+\xc1sYu\xc2\x02^<@\xa2\x10(\x87\xadE\x99G4\xe3\x9b\x815>.\xa6:\xe2\xca\xe7\xec\xf3\x9a+l\x86\'b\xa9\r\xcc\x8b\x9b\xca\x89xt\x92\x8c\xb9\xf7\xd3,\xb3\x0c\x9c\xd4;$b\xc66\xfa&\xa9\xe5\xaa\x14saXO\x15\xf6\x19\x96K\x7f\x8a\x88|\x00\x83\xe5\x95m\xc8\x10\xd3\x89L-"\x8e(\xd55\x12\x10B[,\xdb\xaa\xf6Jp,\xb6\xe1 \x13\x0cT\x0e])\xb2\xcf\x7f\xff\xc0\xae|%-\x1d\t\x18\x9bR\xba\x82\x01!\x93R|\xdf\x03\xf8Ap9\xde\xa5\x02\x81\x00\xd5\xa5\xadcz\xd0\xe8\x8e\x91\x04:\xa3!Hn\x1ezz\x8ax\xc8\xce\xec\x01]L@F\xf6\xc7^-=S\xb1\xb2\xae\xc8\xa4\xfa\xb6\xdf\x96T\xbc\x93\xe7\x18\xd6\x1b\xdc0z~{o\xee\xa2{\r\x03\xa4`\xf8\xbf%8\xd88\xe4\x81x\xd6I\xb1\xe4\xc7m\xbb\xc0\xc6\xd6:\xa3Z\x98\'\xd7\xfd\x10\x9av>\xad\xb2\x17\xa5\xeccb\xe5\xbf\xb5\xa3PH\xb1\x1b\xed \xc3\xdas\x8b\xb58X\x95fp\x14\xba\xbf\x04\x84+\x98?\x12r\xd9\xd6u\xfa@{,\xbbb$\xf2\xca\xd2\xa3\xbd\xfbQ\xc0\xde\x88\t\xd6\x9bc\xe4\x83\x15\xc0\xf3\x1eQ\xcd*UZ\xc9x\x1b^@\xd7\x87\xa1\xea)zx\xb3\xd7\xcc\n\xd0\xd9\x07\xb2\x89@\xc3\xc9\x81\x9d\x15k\x86\x95\x07\xc1\xcf<\x98.\x17'
```

Now, my understanding is that these are hex codes, and there would be a "decoded" version of this.
Now, for some reason, I copied a portion of the string, assigned it to a variable, and printed it normally, it gave a "decoded" version (it was random gibberish, though, but it works)

```
print('\x98l*Y\xdf\xec-\x8eZ8\x05c\xd3\xf2K\xe2\x89\x185\xcd[\xc6\xbfs\xc4\x806D\xee\x9d]\x10\x9c&H\xe7o\xabi\x03\xa6\xb8\xbd\xe9\x8d\xe2\x9cXE\xb5P\xb7\xcd\xa86h\xf1po\\S\x88\x01\x0e \r\x19T#\x0cL\xdf\x18\xc8$5l\xfb\x8c\x01\xa1\xf9\x84\x93\xcd\xd42\x11\x95\xad\xf0\xd2\xcf7\x95\x1a\x19\x14)\xb8\xb9\xe5\x06-\\\x17\xfcm5j\xf5\xfd4\xfc\xfb\x87J\x9d\xf3\x9b\xed\x83\xdc\xed\x18+\xec\xd0\x9e\xd1\xd8\xbe.\x85=;\x1f\x13\x97\xee\xed\xdc\xf3\xbb\xb9\x1d\xcel\x1b\xb7\xb7\xdd\xbe~\x98\xbd8>\xfb\xf0\xe1\x92T\xcb\xf4\x89\xae\x8be\x96\xc0\xe4t7l\xd8\xf5U\xb3\xb8\xc1nI\x1e\x86\xb4\x19_@\xf6Big\xc4P\xdb\xc9\xa0\x1d\xbf-}\x05Cp\x17\x00("\xccV \x96\xd1\x94U&k\xfe\x0cy\x81\x81\x8e^\x85')
```

The output of the previous line is as follows

```
T#                          âXEµP·Í¨6hñpo\S 
Z8LßÈ$5lû¡ùÆ¿sÄ6Dî&Hço«i¦¸½é
           ÍÔ2­ðÒÏ7�)¸¹å-\üm5jõý4üûJÜí+ìÐ
=;îíÜó»¹Îl·Ý¾~TËô   ®eÀät7lØõU³¸ÁnI´_@öBigÄPÛÉ ¿-}Cp("ÌV ÑU&kþ
                                                                  y^
```

And the output was encrypted gibberish.
Then I tried doing the whole string through the copy-paste mechanism, and it worked.

However, when I try to run it through the script going line by line by using `str(<bytes object here>)` and removing the unnecessary parts (the leading *b'* and the ending '), I am still getting the string with all the \x codes.

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    binary_string = data[i][:-1]
    binary_string = binascii.unhexlify(binary_string)
    binary_string = str(binary_string)[2:-1]
    print(binary_string)
```

Where data is the result of file.readlines().

Can someone help me understand what's happening and why a simple copy-paste method works while running it through the loop doesn't work?

Answer (score 3):

The `bytes` object you get back with the representation beginning

```
b'\x82\t\x9f\xd4\xe8d13\xb8T\xc8B#\x1e3\xfe\x99`\x1a\xdf\xbb2\xf... etc
```

is actually a list of integers in the range 0..255. You will see this if you do

```
>>> x = b'\x82\t\x9f\xd4\xe8d13\xb8T\xc8B#\x1e3\xfe\x99`\x1a\xdf\xbb2\xf... etc
>>> list(x)
[130, 9, 159, 212, 232, 100, 49, 51, 184, 84, 200, 66, 35, 30, ...etc
```

The backslashes aren't part of the data: they are the *representation* of the data when byte values are displayed as a bytestring. For example, the 2nd value as shown in the integer list is 9. In the bytestring display it is shown as `\t` which is an ascii horizontal tab, for which the byte value is 9 (or ctrl-i if you prefer). Similarly, the 6th to 8th integer values are `100, 49, 51` which are the ascii values for the characters 'd', '1', '3'; and if you look closely you will see them in the bytestring representation as `d13` between the bytes `\xe8` and `\xb8`. You see `d13` because those bytes can be represented as ascii characters. On either side of that you see `\xe8` and `\xb8` because those bytes have the values 232 and 184, which can not be represented as ascii characters, and so are displayed as hex escapes.

But if you try to process the bytestring representation *as a sequence of characters*, which is what happens when you call `str()` on it, and throw away the enclosing `b'...'`, then it is no longer a sequence of byte values, but rather a bunch of characters that once represented a bytestring. Then you are more or less on your own.

You are probably wondering why Python's default representation of bytestrings is a mixture of hex escapes like `\xe8`, shortcuts like `\t`, and printable characters. There are a couple of good reasons for this, one being that bytestrings are often text, and `b'Hello World'` is friendlier than `b'\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x20\x57\x6f\x72\x6c\x64'`.

To confirm this, paste that bytestring at a Python interpreter prompt, like this:

```
>>> b'\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x20\x57\x6f\x72\x6c\x64'
b'Hello World'
```